# (error) \tightlist (converting .md file into .pdf using pandoc)

Tags: errors, pandoc

I was converting 'lecture1.md' file I made via Rstudio into 'lecture1.pdf'
using Pandoc at Mac Terminal.

and I got this error message :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \tightlist 

l.213 \end{frame}

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
make: *** [lecture1.pdf] Error 43
```

What's strange thing is the same procedure with same files works with my colleague's computer.

Anyone's any comments would be helpful, and I'd appreciate them.

Comment: Compare the log-files to find out what is different on your colleagues computer.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer 
Could you give me some tips where I can find the log files ? I'm not familiar with those stuff.

Comment: Use pandoc to create a standalone latex file and then compile this separatly.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thx for your help and kindness!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The [`writer.latex` file in 
Pandoc's source code currently defines `\tightlist` as](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/fce3ebb8e023d0f9fd5756503e9264b05571b75a/tests/writer.latex#L61):

```latex
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
```

This is also currently the case in the [default LaTeX template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/4d9a73d767b200a0cf43eeab7fc114c106f7b37f/default.latex#L132), from the [`jgm/pandoc-templates` project on Github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/).

For posterity, here is a link to the most up-to-date LaTeX default template:

- https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex

Comment: The `\tightlist` problem seems to arise only when using `-` to build the list, and not when using `*`. (Tested with `pandoc` 1.17.0.3, used through R Markdown in RStudio on Mac OS X.)

Comment: @Fr. `\tightllist` appears when using `*` too (pandoc 2.7.3).

Answer (score 30):

I hit the same problem. It seems that pandoc started using `\tightlist` in `\begin{itemize}` sections.

My workaround was simply to add an empty macro for `\tightlist` to my template file (I run pandoc with `--template=mytemplate.tex`):

`\def\tightlist{}`

Comment: simple and noninvasive. Perfect. It works.

Answer (score 18):

Pandoc doesn't use `\tightlist` if you leave a blank line between each item, e.g.

```
- one

- two
```

versus

```
- one
- two
```

The same is true for enumerated lists. This is the LaTeX version of "loose" and "compact" lists documented here: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#lists (h/t [mb21](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2383#issuecomment-137385423)).