# Pandoc breaks hyperlinks in LaTeX file conversion

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, conversion, pandoc, epub

I want to convert a (quite complex) LaTeX file to epub using pandoc with:

```
pandoc -S file.tex -o file.epub
```

I have not used markdown in the creation of the tex file, however. When I, now, check the generated epub file I see that all hyperlinks (made by hyperref) are broken and thinks like this appear instead:

`Fig. [fig:initial_model]`, `s. Table [tab:dis-advantages]` or `chapter [ch:findings]`.

A check of the epub file displays the following error message:

```
Non-registered URI scheme type found in href.
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: you can try [tex4ebook](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ebook?lang=en)

Comment: Hi Michal.h21, can you elaborate a bit further, for example, how one can use this within the command line without changing the code?

Comment: if you have TL 2015 installed, you can try to run `tex4ebook filename`. it will create epub2 file by default. You shouldn't need to change your TeX file, unless you use some package which isn't supported by `tex4ht` (which `tex4ebook` uses for LaTeX to html conversion)

Comment: Uh, it might still take some time to arrive on archlinux, I guess, see [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.arch.general/54490).

Comment: you can also try to [install it](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/blob/master/INSTALL.md) yourself

Comment: I just tried it and got an `Undefined control sequence` error for `\tightlist` during `make`. [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257418/error-tightlist-converting-md-file-into-pdf-using-pandoc) seems to be a solution but I do not know if and how this would function with installing `tex4ebook` manually.

Comment: `\tighlist` seems to be included by `pandoc`. solution from the linked question should work, I think

Comment: Unfortunately, pandoc currently doesn't seem to support internal links to tables and figures ([#813](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/813), though that seems strongly tied to pandoc's Markdown). Concerning chapters, you probably need to use `\hyperdef{}{chap-one}{\chapter{One}}\label{chap-one}` and `\hyperref[chap-one]{One}` as pandoc does when converting from Markdown, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282583/430). Maybe you can find some relevant `hypersetup` switches in the default LaTeX template (`pandoc -D latex` as well.