# How to change Pandoc's / hyperref's reference format?

Tags: hyperref, pandoc

`\frontmatter`

As described in [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100209/430), `pandoc` turns Markdown links such as

```markdown
[TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)
```

into

```
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX.SE}
```

However, in contrast to what is stated there, the current version of pandoc turns

```markdown
# A section
Linking to [A section]
```

or

```markdown
# A section {#a-section}
Linking to [A section](a-section)
```

both into

```
\hyperdef{}{a-section}{\section{A section}}\label{a-section}
Linking to \hyperref[a-section]{A section}
```

i.e. it uses `\hyperref` and not `\href`.

---

`\mainmatter`

I would like to change the formatting of the reference pandoc creates, preferably via my custom class `custom.cls` I tell pandoc to use (via `documentclass: custom` in the Markdown-document's YAML-Header). So I tried this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\orghyperref\hyperref
\renewcommand*{\hyperref}[2]{\orghyperref[#1]{\texttt{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\hyperdef{}{a-section}{\section{A section}}\label{a-section}
Linking to \hyperref[a-section]{A section}
\end{document}
```

which unfortunately renders the link as

> Linking to a-section]A section

instead. What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the referred-to label is passed in brackets `[]` instead of braces `{}`, the command redefinition must provide some kind of default, i.e. add another pair of brackets behind the `[2]`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\orghyperref\hyperref  %↓↓
\renewcommand*{\hyperref}[2][]{\orghyperref[#1]{\texttt{#2}}}
%                           ↑↑ that's all that changed

\begin{document}
\hyperdef{}{a-section}{\section{A section}}\label{a-section}
Linking to \hyperref[a-section]{A section}
\end{document}
```

I am however quite certain that this will break should the second version of that command,

```
\hyperref{URL}{category}{name}{text}
```

ever be used, but I really haven't bothered enough with [`\@ifnextchar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57788/430) to properly treat that case...